# Strange behavior - getElementById()

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm currently working on something simple - a JavaScript script that makes some minimal validation if a string is an email.

But a problem occurred and I can't seem to understand it.

I have an input text field, where the user enters an email, a button, which when clicked, get's the string from the input and displays it in a div with a green background, if valid, or a red one - if invalid.

So, I have made a function get(), which simply does return a DOM element with on given id. Nothing fancy, but the strange thing comes next.

When I try to use an element, which I've 'got' from the DOM with this function in a callback function, I simply can't. But when in the callback function I manually get it with **document.getElementById('status')**, it works.

I don't understand where is the problem.

Here's my *Html*:

```
<section>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter an email" id="input" />
    <input type="submit" value="Validate &rarr;" id="submit" />
    <div class="status" id="status"></div>
</section>
```

And here's the *JS*:

```
var get = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var input   = get('input'),
    status  = get('status'),
    btn     = get('submit');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // doesn't work
    status.innerHTML = 'Checking...';

    // works?!
    // Puts 'Checking' text in div#status
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Checking...';
});
```

Comment: when does this JS code run first? Because the DOM might not be ready when you first initialize the status variable, but it is obviously ready when the click event handler runs.

Comment: Your JavaScript is probably running before your DOM has finished rendering.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Please undelete that answer. It also appears to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put this code

```
window.onload = function() { 
 var input   = get('input'),
     status  = get('status'),
     btn     = get('submit'); 

 btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // doesn't work
    status.innerHTML = 'Checking...';

    // works?!
    // Puts 'Checking' text in div#status
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Checking...';
 });
};
```

it should work.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as the right answer it works for you

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit nasty problem where a global variable with name `status` won't take non string values... if you try to assign one then it will take the toString() value of that object(have tested in chrome).

In your console if you log the value of `status` you should get `[object HTMLDivElement]` which is the toString() implementation of `Element` object.

Just rename the variable and you should be fine

```
var get = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var input   = get('input'),
    status1  = get('status'),
    btn     = get('submit');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // doesn't work
    status.innerHTML = 'Checking...';

    // works?!
    // Puts 'Checking' text in div#status
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Checking...';
});
```

The same is true for other key window properties like `name`

Comment: Wait whaaaat o.O I had to test that in my console... That's messed up! Example: `var status = {a: 1}` returns `"[object Object]"` while `var status1 = {a: 1} ` returns `Object {a: 1}`

Comment: Thanks, @ArunPJohny, this was the problem! It worked with another indentifier. Which is still strange, because I've tried before with 'st', 'stat' and still didn't work.